# GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW performance spikes

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, c++-chrono

I'm working on my own game engine in C++ with OpenGL, and currently working on the UI. Because I wanted the UI to be scale nicely with different screens, every time there's a window resize it subs in some vertex data to the buffer so the width is consistent.

```c
void UICanvas::windowResize(int width, int height) {
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator itr = wIndices.begin(); itr != wIndices.end(); itr++) {
        UIWindow& window = uiWindows.at(*itr);
        float newX = window.size.x / (100.0f * (*aspectRatio));
        float newY = window.size.y / 100.0f;

        float newPositions = {
            newX, 0.0f,
            newX, -newY
        };

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, window.positions_vbo);
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::timepoint start, end;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { //For benchmarking purposes
            start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 16, 16, &newPositions[0]);
            end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            //The duration of glBufferSubData is all I care about
            printEvent("windowResize", start, end); //Outputs to json for profiling
        }
    }
}
```

Knowing it would be updated occasionally, I knew I should probably use GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW. However, instead of just listening to people I wanted to benchmark the difference myself. For GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW, most of the resize function calls were 3-5 microseconds, with steady occasional spikes of 180-200 microseconds, and even more sparse spikes up to 4 milliseconds, 1000x the normal value. GL_STATIC_DRAW, while the average was 7-13 ms, only spiked up to 100-150 microseconds, but almost rarely. I know there are thousands of factors that can affect benchmarking, like the CPU caching values, or optimizing certain things, but it would almost make more sense if STATIC_DRAW followed the same giant spike pattern. I think I read somewhere that dynamic buffers are stored in VRAM and static ones in regular RAM, but would that be the reason for this behavior? If I use DYNAMIC_DRAW, will it have occasional spikes, or is it due to the repeated calls?

EDIT: Apologies if this was confusing, but the for loop in the code is my testing method, I am looping the same exact function over and over again, and timing only the buffer sub data, as that's where I'm looking for the difference between STATIC_DRAW and DYNAMIC_DRAW.

Comment: Not really an answer, but wouldn't it be way more efficient to define the ui in [0,1] space and add a scaling matrix for the window size? Even a vec2 scaling factor uniform would be enough.

Comment: Well I wanted the UI to be independent of aspect ratio, so the UI canvas has y values of -100 to 100, and in the case of 16:9 (1.77) the x values are -177.7 to 177.7. The windows are defined with anchor points to the screen, that way they look consistent.

Comment: @TyStaszak: Does this code accurately represent how you're uploading data to the buffer in the actual program? That is, are you uploading 16 bytes at a time for *thousands* of UI elements?

Comment: @NicolBolas Now that you say that, I realize it's probably not the best idea to change all the buffer data for every UI window each time the window is resized. I was prioritizing rendering over less common events (resize), but it's probably not that slow to just store the aspect ratio as a uniform and scale the UI windows in the vertex shader.

Comment: @BDL I didn't understand what you were saying before but now I do.

Comment: @TyStaszak: It's not so much *that* you're changing it, but *how* you're changing it. A single upload of *all* of the data to the buffer, all at once, would be better than doing it 16 bytes at a time. Or map the buffer, write your stuff, and unmap it. Or persistent map the buffer and write to it as needed. Basically [doing any of this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) would be better than the way you're doing it.

Comment: Nicol is right, the for loop with buffer looks like the culprit here, you want to keep the glBuffer{Sub}Data calls to a minimum. It doesn't even look like newPositions is being updated inside the loop but maybe I'm missing something. The other thing, you have printEvent inside your loop, which I'm assuming is a synchronous operation, which will eat up all your cpu time. Your "profiling" should never be injecting IO into code, instead use a normal profiler like XTune.

Comment: @MudkipHacker Sorry if my code was confusing, but I have the for loop in there to show how I'm benchmarking the function. For the actual function, it's just called once but I just wanted to compare the difference of DYNAMIC_DRAW vs STATIC_DRAW. And while the profiling is intrusive and increases time of the for loop, what I'm measuring is the single glBufferSubData function, where I'm grabbing the time points before and after, to find the true duration.

Comment: "And while the profiling is intrusive and increases time of the for loop, what I'm measuring is the single glBufferSubData function," But that is meaningless. GL implementations do all sorts of stuff behind your back, and are usually multithreaded anyway. You measure what you measure, but drawing actually useful conculsions is a completely different topic.

Comment: Also, those hints should be avoided at all costs anyway. We have the much better buffer storage interface since 10 years now, and for your use case, a persistently mapper BO with manual synchronization seems like what you really want if you care about performance.

Comment: This would also avoid most issues like "driver from vendor A in version B at moon phase C tends to spike in perfomance by amount D if hint is set to E'.

Comment: @TyStaszak I think you can try using much higher amount of data being buffered. The benefits of dynamic draw for thousand iterations might not be evident here with the tiny 16 byte buffer. I'm not sure if derhass is correct, I think from our perspective the glBufferSubData is synchrounous, and we can rely on the start and finish times.

Comment: With all that said, if this issue/question is only limited to screen resizing, I feel that lag isn't that important, modern games make you wait 2-4 seconds and restart their render context when changing render buffer size anyways. Although a screen resize based game might blow everyone's minds.